# Simulating a resizeable airplay display

Tags: ios, airplay

Im working on an iOS application that supports external displays over airplay, I do most of my testing with the external display option in the simulator, and some on iOS devices connected to macs running various airplay receiver apps.
Im now attempting to support an external display whose size changes, and I don't have access to the the device to test with(And I can't say what the device is).

I've noticed in the documentation for UIScreen the UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification:

> Clients can use this notification to detect changes in the screen resolution.

This notification supposedly gets triggered for the device i'm trying to support, and it seems this is where I should handle resizing the UI to respond to this change.

Are there any ways to simulate an airplay display that can be resized, and on resize will post a UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many displays support multiple resolutions. When the resolution changes on the display it will re-negotiate the new resolution with the iPad and the notification will be triggered. Try changing the display's resolution while the iPad is plugged in via a video adaptor.